# Odds-Ratio in Comprehensive Meta-Analysis

Tags: meta-analysis, computational-statistics, odds-ratio

I am conducting a meta analysis and using the program Comprehensive Meta-Analysis. 
I have a problem with one of the Odds-Ratios I inserted.
The program.
It is now colored in red and it is written that the lower and upper limits are not symmetric.
These are the original numbers from the study I'm using, what can I do with it? If left unchanged, these numbers won't be calculated in the meta analysis, so I have to change it somehow.

thanks!

Comment: This has happened to me before. It's rare, but could be a rounding or reporting error.

Answer (score 1):

You have a number of choices.

See how far each (log) limit is from the central (log) estimate. If the difference is small and could possibly be accounted for by rounding error then adjust one of them to make it symmetric and report that fact in your report.

Write to the authors of the primary study and ask them.

Assume the one furthest from the central one is right, back-calculate the standard error and re-compute the erroneous limit. This rests on a lot of assumptions and I would be very cautious about doing it myslef.